# Bibliographic References on the number of invariant subspaces of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

I need bibliographic references on the number of invariant subspaces of a linear transformation. Is there any application for counting the invariant subspaces?

Comment: I suggest you start [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_subspace_problem), for bounded operators on Banach spaces this is unknown.